# Pretty-print Nested Hash-map in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is there a convenient way in ClojureScript to pretty print a nested hash-map in the way that the whole tree-structure becomes immediately visible.

For instance a map like this

```
(def my-map {:a {:b 1 :c 9} :b {:d 8 :e {:f 2 :g 3 :h 4}} :c 10})
```

should be printed like this:

```
{:a {:b 1
     :c 9}
 :b {:d 8
     :e {:f 2
         :g 3
         :h 4}}
 :c 10}
```

*EDIT:* There might also be vectors in the map. The usecase is just to inspect larger data structures during development.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to do it. You might come close to what you want by using `cljs.pprint` and setting `cljs.pprint/*print-right-margin*` to a low value.

I would recommend to take a look at a small library [shodan](https://github.com/noprompt/shodan) which provides a very useful [`inspect`](https://github.com/noprompt/shodan#inspection) function:

```
(require '[shodan.inspection :refer [inspect]])

(inspect {:aaaaaa 1
          :bbbbbb {:ccc 2
                   :dddddd [1 2 3 4 5]}})
```

It won't print anything in your CLJS REPL but will provide a handy view in your browser's console:

[image]

You can collapse and expand nested datastructures - it basically does what you asked for.

Comment: nice way, but when the output exceeds 10 it will be pretty ugly: `(def my-map {:a {:b 1 :c 9} :b {:d 8 :e {:f 2 :g 3 :h 4}} :c "sssssssssssssssssss"})`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Recently I discovered a small library which does a good job in such cases. I have added information about it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a personal challenge I wrote the following code:

```
(enable-console-print!)
(def atomic? (complement coll?))
(def padding #(apply str (repeat % " ")))
(def tabulate #(apply str (repeat % "\t")))
(def strcat #(->> (apply concat %&) (apply str)))
(defn my-max-key [x] (if (empty? x) [""] (apply (partial max-key count) x)))
(defn longest-key [m] (->> m keys (filter atomic?) (map str) my-max-key))
(def length (comp count str))
(def not-map? (complement map?))
(def nested? #(some coll? %))
(def join #(apply str (interpose % %2)))
(def join-lines (partial join "\n"))
(defn has-atomic? [coll] (some atomic? coll))
(defn diff-key-lengths [key1 key2] (- (length key1) (length key2)))
(defn convert
  ([thing] (convert -1 thing))
  ([depth thing]
   (defn convert-items []
     (defn convert-seq []
       (conj []
             (map (partial convert (inc depth)) thing)
             ""))
     (defn string-horizontally [[key value]]
       (str (tabulate (inc depth))
            key
            (padding (diff-key-lengths (longest-key thing) key))
            " → "
            value))
     (defn string-vertically [[key value]]
       (str (convert (inc depth) key) "\n"
            (convert (+ 2 depth) "↓") "\n"
            (convert (inc depth) value) "\n"))
     (defn convert-kv [[key value]]
       (if (nested? [key value])
           (string-vertically [key value])
           (string-horizontally [key value])))
     (cond (atomic? thing)
           [(str (tabulate depth) thing)]

           (not-map? thing)
           (convert-seq)

           (map? thing)
           (map convert-kv thing)))
   (->>  (convert-items) flatten join-lines)))

(def sample-input [["the first thing in this nested vector"]
                   {{"this is a key in a nested map"
                    "that points to me!!!"}
                   {"and that entire map points to this map!!!"
                    "cool!!!"
                    "but it gets cooler cause..."
                    "the value's line up!!!"}}])
(->> sample-input convert println)
```

The terminal output is (psst... the values in a map do line up but I don't think that chrome uses a monospaced font!):
[image: chrome screenshot of index.html]